# Safe to delete "Recovered Messages" Mailbox in Apple Mail on Mac?

Tags: mac, mail.app, email, gmail

**A "Mailbox" (visible on the left sidebar on Apple Mail on Mac) was created called "Recovered Messages (Google)", I am using my Gmail account in Mail. It is categorized under "On My Mac".**

I believe that any messages which are not sent successfully sometimes get placed there (attachments too large etc).

**I have no messages in the folder and prefer not to see it with the assumption that if necessary it would be created again. Is it safe for me to delete the folder?**

I've searched for the answer but most people are asking for help deleting the actual messages the folder contains, not deleting the folder itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get one such folder occasionally after I run a script to perform some housekeeping. I simply right-click and delete it, and **Mail** creates it anew the next time it needs it.

If your folder is empty, it should be safe to delete it.